# Packaging System.Data.SqlClient with a class library in C#

Tags: c#, class-library, sqlclient

I have a scanner add-in that I'm working on that uses C#.

My code works on the emulator, but not on the scanner hardware itself.  Could it be because the scanner doesn't have System.Data.SqlClient on it?  I'm not sure.  Is there a way I can specify that System.Data.SqlClient be included in my generated dll file?

The error I get is Named Pipes Provider error 40 on con.Open().  If it were a problem with the scanner not having the library though, woudln't it throw on error at the first reference to a SqlConnection?  The source code is as follows:

```
String clientName = "";

        try
        {
            // Setting up the SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder buildIt = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            buildIt.DataSource = "xxx.xx.x.xx";
            buildIt.InitialCatalog = "database";
            buildIt.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(buildIt.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM background WHERE Patient_No=@Patient_No", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_No", clientID);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        clientName = reader.GetString(0).Trim() + " " + reader.GetString(1).Trim();
                    } // end if (reader.hasRows)
                    else
                    {
                        // No client found for this ID.
                        return false;
                    } // end else
                } // end using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM background WHERE Patient_No=@Patient_No", con))
            }
        } // end try
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            // Test code.
            // MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            exporterHost.WriteSystemLog(LogType.Error, "E9999999", "SQL ERROR: " + err.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient is part of System.Data.dll.

Comment: I have a reference to that in my project.  Is there any way to have that included with the compiled .dll file?

Comment: System.Data.dll is part of the framework, you shouldn't need to package it in your app

Comment: Sounds more like a simple connection problem. Your database just isn't reachable via Named Pipes. If needed Classes/Assemblies etc. aren't available the exception would say so.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The confusing thing is that it works on the scanner emulator, but not the scanner hardware.